# Обновить контент только одного блока

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Попытаюсь вкратце описать суть проблемы. Я делаю сайт в одну страницу, но с множеством всплывающих окон. Там можно получать баллы и тратить их на разные призы. Из за того, что все построено на всплывающих окнах, везде где нужно отправлять формы - использовал ajax. Но тут всплыла проблема: у меня вверху блока расположен блок где отображаются очки юзера. Когда он кладет какой то приз в корзину - то кол-во очков должно уменьшится. В базе оно уменьшается, а вот на странице - нет, ибо страница из - за ajax'а не перезагружается... Собственно вопрос: как можно обновить отдельный блок? Просто перезагрузить страницу нельзя - все открытые всплывающие окна захлопнутся. Заранее спасибо за совет!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

делаете запрос на получение нового значения из БД:

```
$.post(
  'get_value.php',//файл-обработчик должен возвращать новое значение
  {
    'передаваемый_параметр':'значение' //если нужно
  },
  function(data)
  {
     $("#ид_вашего_отдельного_блока").text(data);
  }
);
```

Comment: то, что jQuery уже почти стандарт для javascript, это понятно, но стоило бы уточнить, что Ваш код написан с его помощью.

Comment: А это-то тут причем?

Comment: Спасибо большое) Разобрался )